# Alternative way of Fetching Data in Mongo rather than URI's

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Using Express & Node as my Middleware, I am using `app.get('/:email/:password')` and it finds the users like so:  `users.find({email. req.params.email, password: req.params.password}).toArray());`

On the frontend I just have a `fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user' + '/' + email + '/' + password)`

Although this works. Is there a better way of doing this? I'm not sure if passing the email & password to the URI is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‍ You can do it using `Post` method. For an example, you can look at this code below :

**Frontend:**

```js
async handlePost() {
  try {
    // change the endpoint with yours
    const userobject = { email, password };
    // you can change wit your endpoint
    const endpoint =  'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users';
    const result = await fetch( endpoint, { method: 'POST',data: JSON.stringfy(userobject)  })
    const json = await result.json();
    console.log(json);
    // do some stuff here: set state or some stuff you want
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
}
```

The code above  only an example. Your `userobject` can from your state or you passing it to your function `handlePost`.

**Backend:**

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// enable req.body
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/v1/users', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
        const result = await users.find({email, password}).toArray();
        res.status(200).send(result);
    } catch(ex) {
        res.status(500).send(ex.message);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is up');
})
```

The code above only  an example backend that you can use to handle your frontend post request.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Would you say this is better than using GET? For authentication purposes? Or if no, why? I'm new to all of this.